# UISlider adding target action not working

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am having trouble creating a UISlider through swift programmatically. The error is saying the selector I have is unrecognized. I have tried using the form of "#selector(function)", but it does not work either. Here is my code:

```
let windTurbineView = SKView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 325, height: 600)))
let windSpeedSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 280, height: 18)))

func windSpeedSliderSetUp() {
    windSpeedSlider.minimumValue = 0.0
    windSpeedSlider.maximumValue = 20.0
    windSpeedSlider.isContinuous = true
    windSpeedSlider.tintColor = .blue
    windSpeedSlider.minimumValueImage = UIImage(named: "0MPH.png")
     windSpeedSlider.maximumValueImage = UIImage(named: "20MPH.png")
    windSpeedSlider.value = 0
    windTurbineView.addSubview(windSpeedSlider)
    windSpeedSlider.center.x = windTurbineView.center.x
    windSpeedSlider.center.y = 585
    windSpeedSlider.addTarget(windSpeedSlider, action: Selector(("sliderValueDidChange")), for: .valueChanged)
}

 func sliderValueDidChange(sender: UISlider) {

    mphLabel.text = "\(sender.value)"
    print("wi")
}
```

I am using swift playgrounds and have the following imported: UIKit, PlaygroundSupport, and SpriteKit.

Here is a screenshot of my console too: [image: consoleLog]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the method `sliderValueDidChange()` is defined in the View Controller but the target of the `windSpeedSlider` is set to the `windSpeedSlider` itself. Instead you should set the target to `self` (i.e., the view controller):

```
windSpeedSlider.addTarget(self, action:#selector(sliderValueDidChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

The target is the object to which the message / selector is sent.

Answer (score 1):

Your `addTarget` should be:

```
windSpeedSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueDidChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Check it out:

[image: Check it out]